# How to custom this image tab in UIView,using @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable is better

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

How to draw the following tab image in UIView?The text is changeable,which implies that the image could stretch in width. And I know in XCode6,it supports live render.So I think if possible,it's color,text,and size could be set in attributes inspector.

[image: tab image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a custom class, based on UIView. This class is declared as `@IBDesignable` and has `@IBInspectable` properties. Override `UIView.drawRect()` and you are totally free on how your view gets displayed.

Here is a sample class to get you started.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyTabView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable tabTitle: String = ""
    @IBInspectable tabColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Initialization code
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        // stuff for interface builder only
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        // this is where your view gets drawed
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question,I add a corresponding xib for this custom view,and I add some UIControls into this xib,when I use this customView in storyboard(change class to my view in Identity Inspector,only the code I write render in storyboard,except for those UIControls I pulled from object library.